# Knexjs how to handle multiple updates

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I´m quite unsure on how to handle multiple updates / inserts in knex and return whatever it was successfull on the end or not.

I´m passing an array through req.body loop through it and trigger actions based on informations inside the array.

Example:

```
const data = [...req.body]
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i].totals.length
        for(let y = 0; y < data[i].totals.length; y++) {
            if(data[i].totals[y].info === "Holiday") {
                calcHoliday(data[i].totals[y].total, data[i].id)
            } else if(data[i].totals[y].info === "ZA") {
                calcZA(data[i].totals[y].total, data[i].id)
            }
        }
        calcOvertime(data[i].totalSum, data[i].id)

        if(i === data.length -1) {
            res.json("Success")
        }
    }
```

The Array I´m passing in looks like this:

```
[
    {
    "id": 1,
    "totals": [
        {
            "info": "Holiday",
            "total": 4
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "id": 1,
    "totals": [
        {
            "info": "Holiday",
            "total": 4
        }
    ]
    }
]
```

Function Example which gets called in for loop:

```
const calcHoliday = (hours, userid) => {
        knex.transaction(trx => {
            trx.insert({
                created_at: convertedTime,
                info: "Booking Holiday - Hours: " + hours,
                statuscode: 200
            }).into("logs")
                .then(() => {
                    return trx("hours")
                        .decrement("holiday_hours", hours)
                }).then(trx.commit)
                .catch(trx.rollback)
        }).then(() => console.log("WORKED"))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

This is working perfectly fine but I can´t figure out how to gather the results from each table update in order to respond if everything worked or an error appeared. If I call e.g. after one calcHoliday call `.then(resp => res.json(resp)` I receive only the response from the first operation.

In short I need a way on how to res.json if everything succeeded or an error appeared somewhere.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TLDR;

Turning your insert calls into an array of promises and then using `await` and a `Promise.all()` / `Promise.allSettled()` structure might solve this problem, but there are some UX decisions to make on what to rollback and how to return errors.

#### Error Handling Choices:

1. **Any error --> *all* insertions in all loop iterations should be rolled back**

- Do you want partial success? The way the code is written now, rollback only applies to items in one function call. If one of the `hour-decrement` calls fails, it will roll back one `log` insert, but not any that succeeded for previous data in the loop. If you want the whole dataset to rollback, you'd need to pass the `txn` through each function call *or* do a bulk insert of all of your rows in one function call, which might be nice for performance reasons anyway depending on the use case.

2. **Partial success --> commits successes, rolls back single loop iterations that fail, sends detailed list of errors and successes**

- You'd want to use `Promise.allSettled()`, which aggregates the successes and errors as an array from all promises in the loop.

3. **Partial success --> commits the successes, rolls back single loop iterations that fail, sends just one error**

- Opinion: This can be a misleading UX unless the error is "some of the insertions were unsuccessful" and the endpoint is idempotent
- This looks closest to what you're describing you want. If this is the case, you'd want to use `Promise.all()`, which throws an error as soon as one promise in the array errors.

#### Example Implementation:

Since the original code is incomplete, this is a loose, incomplete example of what option 2/3 might look like. This could easily be transformed into option 1.

First, it might help to modify all of your functions with asynchronous calls to be fulfillable as promises. Async/await helps avoid .then() trees that are hard to reason about.

```
const calcHoliday = async (hours, userid) => {
  try {
    const result = await knex.transaction(async(trx) => {
      await trx.insert({
        created_at: convertedTime,
        info: "Booking Holiday - Hours: " + hours,
        statuscode: 200
      }).into("logs")

      return trx("hours").decrement("holiday_hours", hours)
    }

    return result
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("It didn't work.")
    throw new Error(`Error: Failure to insert for user ${userid}:`, err)
  }
}
```

Here are some utilities to get the data transformed, and to get the appropriate unfulfilled promise to supply to the map in Promise.all/allSettled.

```
/*
 Here's an example of how you might transform the original data with maps in order to avoid nested for-loops:
  [
    { id: 1, info: 'Holiday', total: 4 },
    { id: 1, info: 'Holiday', total: 4 }
  ]
*/
const flatData = data.map(item => {
  return item.totals.map(total => ({
    id: item.id,
    ...total
  }))
}).flat()


// Returns the appropriate promise based on data
const getTotalsPromises = (row) => {
  const {info, id, total} = row
  if(info === "Holiday") {
      return calcHoliday(total, id)
  } else if(info === "ZA") {
      return calcZA(total, id)
  }
}

const getcalcOvertimePromises = (rowInData) = {
  // work left to reader
  return calcOvertime(rowInData.correctData, rowInData.otherData)
}
```

If you want option 2:

```
// Replaces the loop

// Fulfills *all* the promises, creating an array of errors and successes
const responses = await Promise.allSettled([
  ...flatData.map(getTotalsPromises),
  ...data.map(getCalcOvertimePromises)
])

// insert loop here to do something with errors if you want

res.send(responses)
```

**OR** Option 3
Create an array of all of the promises you want to run, run them, and process up to one error.

```
// Replaces the loop

// Runs the promises and waits for them all to finish or the first error.

try {
  const responses = await Promise.all([
    ...flatData.map(getTotalsPromises),
    ...data.map(getCalcOvertimePromises)
  ])
  res.send(responses)
} catch(err){
  // Reached if one of the rows errors
  res.send(err)
}
```

---

Docs:
[Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)
[Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: @Midoxx Out of curiosity, which error handling were you going for?

Comment: depends on the API Endpoint need and how critical one fail would be and if I want to Display specific errors for each case - I actually do have more than one scenario in which I need to Update / insert multiple Data. I´m currently working on rewriting my API provided with your Solution. So far I´ve implemented scenario 3 - for described scenario in this Question I´ll go with solution 2. Thanks again for this great description! Helped a lot also for better understanding Promises.